# Accordion effect in Jade with dynamic ids

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pug, accordion

Currently I have a code where I need the accordion effect in a Jade file with dynamically generated ids. Here's what I have so far -

```
each product in products
  .col-xs-8
    #accordion.panel-group
      #panel1.panel.panel-info
        .panel-heading
          h4.panel-title
            a(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#collapse#{product.id}', href='#collapse#{product.id}')
              | #{product.title}
        |         
        div(id="#collapse#{product.id}").panel-collapse.collapse.in
          .panel-body
            | #{product.description}
      |
```

I'm not able to get the accordion effect for this code. If I replace the dynamic ids with something static like `href='#collapse1'` and `#collapse1.panel-collapse.collapse.in` it would give the accordion effect but only for that id.

Any help is appreciated. I'm new to jade and jquery so excuse me if I have overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the `#accordion` out of the iterator. And each panel's id needs to be dynamic. Also, I believe the `data-target=` should be `#accordion`. 
Here's a working example:

```
.col-xs-8
  #accordion.panel-group
  each product in products
    .panel-info(id="panel#{product.id}")
      .panel-heading
        h4.panel-title
          a(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#accordion', href='#collapse#{product.id}') #{product.title}
      .panel-collapse.collapse.in(id="#collapse#{product.id}")
        .panel-body #{product.description}
```